# import org.apache.zookeeper.Zookeeper can't be resolved maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-zookeeper

I can't import zookeeper in maven project. What can be a problem? I added dependencies but I can't import apache zookeeper

Comment: Which dependencies did you add ?

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
    <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.10</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

Comment: just copied from mavenrepository.com for my zookeeper version

Comment: Can you be more specific ? What error are you getting where and exactly what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to connect java to Zookeeper

Comment: when i write a code java cant resolve zookeeper so it says zookeeper cant be resolved

Comment: Sorry you need to be a bit more specific than that. Are you using an IDE ? Which one - and how was it configured ? Have you tried using maven on the commandline ? Can you add the output from `mvn compile` to your post ?

Comment: My assumption that the `<type>pom</type>` is simply wrong cause I assume also that you like to use the jar file ? If so you have to remove the `<type>pom</type>`...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the
    `pom` in the pom file mentioned by [khmarbaaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise).

So that is only has:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
```